# How to call a function when a value of variable has been changed from the default value in java?

Tags: java, listener

I wish to call a function in Java when a value of particular variable is changed. I do not want to constantly check the value of the variable by setting a time interval, e.g. whenever the value of variable A becomes 1, just call function A. Is there any way to create a Listener for a value of variable?

Comment: Execute the action from your setter? There is an Observable api? What do you mean when the variable is changed?

Comment: when a value of variable is changed to some specific value , i wish to create a listener that would call a particular method

Comment: Actually don't use the [Observable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Observable.html) api it is deprecated, they suggest the java.beans or some data structures in java.concurrent

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the JavaFX (OpenJFX) library, there is the Property class.

```
IntProperty a = new SimpleIntProperty();

a.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
        System.out.printf("%d -> %d%n", oldValue, newValue);

a.set(42);
```

A property wraps some object or type.

In general better use a reactive model like [Flow](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Flow.html).